# Copy table from Word and paste into another Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy, paste

I'm trying to open a Word Document and copy the whole table inside it and then paste it into another already-open document after a specific heading/bookmark (that I have bookmarked in the document). Then finally prompt the user to save the document with the newly pasted table.

Examples seen online are Excel-to-Word or Word-to-Excel; I need Word-to-Word.

I'm able to pull up the first document (I *think* it successfully copies it, too--I haven't tested it), but when it activates the second document, it stops and gives an error that it doesn't have an object assigned.

The debugger highlights `Set WrdRng = Active.Bookmarks("AppendixA").Range`.

```vb
Sub TEST()
'
' Declare Table Document Var as Object
Dim tb As Object
Dim bk As Bookmark
Dim WrdRng As Range
'
'
'Set up Word Application
    Set tb = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    tb.Visible = True

'Opens Pre-Saved Document & activates it to use
    tb.Documents.Open "C:\ Desktop\Table.dotm"
    tb.Activate

    Selection.WholeStory
    'ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Select
    Selection.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    Selection.Copy

'Activate Rolling Trend Report Document and Paste
    Windows("TEST  -  Compatibility Mode").Activate
    
' where the error occurs and the debugger highlights
    Set WrdRng = Active.Bookmarks("AppendixA").Range
    
'Paste to Bookmark
    With WrdRng
        Selection.InsertAfter
    End With

'Save Completed Report to Desktop
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C: \Desktop\"

    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="TEST.docm", _
      FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled
'
'
'
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is your code running from? Word or Excel? The code in your question is not written to run from Word.

Comment: Ohhhh. It is running from Word. I originally did want to run it from Excel (where I have another VBA code that produces the already-open document). Do I need to do anything to adapt it fully for Excel, or would you suggest something else??

Answer (score 0):

Your code is failing because `Set WrdRng = Active.Bookmarks("AppendixA").Range` should be `Set WrdRng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("AppendixA").Range`

However, your code is badly written, will also fail in other places and will create an extra instance of Word.

The code below is to run from Word

```
Sub TEST()
    'store a pointer to the document you wnat to insert table into
    'assumed to be currently active document
    Dim targetDoc As Document
    Set targetDoc = ActiveDocument
    
    'Open Pre-Saved Document
    Dim tblDoc As Document
    Set tblDoc = Documents.Open("C:\ Desktop\Table.dotm")
    Dim source As Range
    Set source = tblDoc.Content
    'exclude the paragraph that comes after the table
    source.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
    source.Font.Name = "Calibri"
        
    Dim appxA As Range
    Set appxA = targetDoc.Bookmarks("AppendixA").Range
    appxA.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    
    'transfer the text and close the source document
    appxA.FormattedText = source.FormattedText
    tblDoc.Close wdDoNotSaveChanges

    'it is necessary to pass the full file path to the SaveAs command
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="C: \Desktop\TEST.docm", _
        FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled
End Sub
```